# Use of macro is producing unexpected output?

Tags: c, macros, printf

The use of the macro `PRINT` in the code below is producing unexpected output in function `q`. Why is the use of macro `PRINT(z)` producing 5 but with `printf` it is producing 12?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PRINT(X) printf("%d\n",x)
int x;
void q(int z) 
{
    z+=x;//7+5=12
    printf("%d\n",z);// here 12 it s good
    PRINT(z); // why 5 here?
}

void p(int *y)
{
     int x;
     x=*y+2;
     q(x);
     *y=x-1;
     printf("%d\n",x);// 7 it is good
     PRINT(x);         // 7 it is good
}

int main()
{
    x=5;
    p(&x);
    printf("%d\n",x);// 5 good
    PRINT(x);      // 5 good
}
```

Comment: Note that the code in `q()` would not compile without the global variable `x`.  The local variable `x` in `p()` hides the global variable; that's usually a bad idea.  GCC supports `-Wshadow` to report when a local variable hides or shadows a global variable.

Comment: Yet another example why global variables are evil

Answer (score 3):

Generally everything in C is case-sensitive, so that your `#define PRINT(X)` macro has `X` (uppercase) as a parameter, but uses only `x` (lowercase) in the substitution.  That happens not to cause an error, because you have an `x` in scope at the time the macro is expanded.

That is, your `PRINT(z)` expands to `printf("%d\n", x)`, and prints `x` (that is, 5) as requested.

Your compiler probably has an option (in gcc and llvm it's `-E`) to show you the post-preprocessor version of your program.